# How to uninstall built in OpenSSH (7.2)?

Tags: openssh, sshd

I would like to ask for your assistance. I have compiled OpenSSH 7.9:

```
sshd -V shows:
OpenSSH_7.9p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019
```

BUT still the built-in one is in service, and I don't know how to get rid of it:

```
nmap
PORT     STATE SERVICE  VERSION
222/tcp  open  ssh      OpenSSH 7.2p2 Ubuntu 4ubuntu2.8 (Ubuntu Linux; protocol 2.0)
```

Could you please assist me, how to delete the 7.2 one and use the 7.9 instead?

Ubuntu version:

- Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
- Kernel: Linux 4.4.0-143-generic

Comment: service ssh restart

Comment: smrt28, thank you for your answer, but unfortunately, the it is the same, and after reboot it is the same.

Comment: Did you just compile sshd? or *install* it? if so, how (`install`? `checkinstall`?) and where (to the default system path `/usr/sbin/`, or to somewhere else such as `/usr/local/sbin`?) Did you modify or supply an alternative `.service` file?

Comment: steeldriver, Thank you very much! Yes, I compiled/installed to location: /usr/sbin. Where can I set to supply as an alternative?